# Android SQLite database onUpgrade method is not called?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Android SQLite helper file has the following methods. I updated my database by adding a column. The DB is upgraded but the changes are not coming into effect. I have changed the version code but still no effect. 
The `onUpgrade` method is not called. Why is that? Is there anything wrong with the `checkdatabase()` method where any writable permission must be used.

```
public class ExternalDbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static String DB_PATH;

public static String DB_NAME;
public SQLiteDatabase database;
public final Context context;

public SQLiteDatabase getDb() {
    return database;
}

public ExternalDbOpenHelper(Context context, String databaseName) {
    super(context, databaseName, null, 2);
    this.context = context;
    //String version_db = ;

    DB_NAME = databaseName;
    String path = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath();
    DB_PATH = path;
    openDataBase();

}


public void createDataBase() {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (!dbExist) {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Copying error");
            throw new Error("Error copying database!");
        }
    } else {
        Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Database already exists");
    }
}

private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;
    try {
        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Error while checking db");
    }

    if (checkDb != null) {
        checkDb.close();
    }
    return checkDb != null;
}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    InputStream externalDbStream = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);


    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;


    OutputStream localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);


    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = externalDbStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        localDbStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    localDbStream.close();
    externalDbStream.close();

}

public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    if (database == null) {
        createDataBase();
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }
    return database;
}
@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (database != null) {
        database.close();
    }
    super.close();
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

     try {
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE UserMaster ADD COLUMN scheme_status 
        TEXT");
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE UserMaster ADD COLUMN location_status 
        TEXT");

     } catch (Exception Exp) {


    }
}


private Context getBaseContext() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    if(newVersion > oldVersion){

        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE UserMaster ADD COLUMN scheme_status TEXT");


    }

}

}
```

Comment: Change to `SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE` in `checkDatabase()` method.

Comment: @Abbasgave it a try but no result..

Comment: Your code for copying DB files around is broken. You should have used [SQLiteAssetHelper](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-sqlite-asset-helper/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the return of openDatabase() method from database to  this.getWritableDatabase() which worked for me.

```
 public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
 String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
 if (database == null) {
    createDataBase();
    database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
 }
 return this.getWritableDatabase();
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

When you change database structure and you would like to execute onUpdate you need to change database version. To do so you need to change the number in the third parameter of super() method that is executed in your constructor. It should be like this:

```
public ExternalDbOpenHelper(Context context, String databaseName) {
    super(context, databaseName, null, 3);
    this.context = context;
    //String version_db = ;

    DB_NAME = databaseName;
    String path = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath();
    DB_PATH = path;
    openDataBase();

}
```

ref: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#SQLiteOpenHelper(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory, int)

Comment: so can you tell me why you are coping some 'database' while constructor of SQLiteOpenHelper is executed? I do not understand what you are trying to do there. I will suggest trying creating database in onCreate of SQLiteOpenHelper. You have got SQLiteDatabase object there where you can define you databases structure. Try to create one table, then update database version an tell me if onUpdate were executed

Comment: In the oncreate method I created the columns needed but once the upgrade is made I need to fill in the columns with values from the server.

Comment: `In the oncreate method I created the columns needed ` your snipped does not show this.

Comment: Maybe you are uninstalling an application from device/emulator just before upgrading DB version? For my solution it always worked, so maybe you have some custom implementations somewhere else that might cause the problem?

Comment: I have tested your code (without this part that copies db files) and onUpdate is executed whenever I update version number. I do not know how do you try to use it in your application but obviously you do it wrong.

Comment: can you pass here snipped of how do you use this database helper? Maybe this will help us figure out what is the problem

Comment: I have an activity which calls the database helper. The activity calls this and then uses the data inside the oncreate method itself..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165342/discussion-between-marisaluht-and-patryk-jablonski).

Comment: ExternalDbOpenHelper dbhelper = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(this,DB_NAME);
SQLiteDatabase database;
database.openDatabase();

Comment: try changing code in open database method to use `return this.getWritableDatabase()`. Most probably code that you use in `openDatabase` method opens database that is different than the one that you define in the constructor. While you use a different database than one that is defined it will not call onUpdate.

Comment: I used this.getWritableDatabase(). And it worked for me.